# MPL Map Instantiate Type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I have the following:

```
class Message
{
public:
    bool process()
    {
        return doProcess();
    }
protected:
    virtual bool doProcess() = 0;
};

class Hello : public Message
{
protected:
    bool doProcess()
    {
        return false;
    }
};
typedef typename boost::mpl::map< boost::mpl::pair< boost::mpl::int_< 0 >, Hello > > map;

struct Generator
{
    typedef void result_type;
    template< typename t_type >
    void operator()(std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< Message > >& processors,
                    t_type p_element)
    {
        typedef typename boost::mpl::at< map, t_type >::type c_instanceType
        boost::shared_ptr< Message > temp(reinterpret_cast< Message* >(new c_instanceType));
        p_processors[p_element] = temp;
    }
};
```

This is then invoke like so:

```
class MessageProcessor
{
public:
    MessageProcessor() :
        m_processors(12)
    {
        // eventually there will be 12 different messages so I will add
        // them to the mpl map and adjust the range
        boost::mpl::for_each< boost::mpl::range_c< boost::uint8_t, 0, 1 > >
        (
            boost::bind(Generator(), boost::ref(m_processors), _1)
    }
private: 
    std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< Message > > m_processors;
};
```

This code compiles cleanly; however, when the function is later invoked like so:

```
m_processors[0]->process();
```

A segmenation fault occurs on the line in the process function that returns do process. I am working in gcc 4.8 with boost version 1.55. Also note this isn't the entire code. When walking through with the debugger I see that the vptr appears to be null when invoking the doProcess, so the child class doesn't seem to exist. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue appears to be that the type is not actually found when doing at<> and something else is being returned instead of the Hello type. It looks like the type that is passed in by `boost::for_each` is of type, `boost::mpl::integral_c<boost::uint8_t, 0>` which doesn't exist in the mpl map since I am storing `boost::mpl::int_<0>` as the key. Changing the key type in the map to `boost::mpl::integeral_c< boost::uint8_t, 0 >` does not segfault and performs as expected.